# What's purpose of the new function BinarySerialize?

Tags: functions, built-in-symbols, compression

*11.1* introduced a new function [`BinarySerialize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinarySerialize.html), but I don't know what it can do better than the traditional method.Its behavior is very similar to `Compress`,though I cannot find any advantage of it.It even consumes more space than `Compress`,such as

`BinarySerialize[Range[100]] // Normal // Length`

> 805

```
Compress[Range[100]] // ToCharacterCode // Length
```

> 290

And `ByteCount[BinarySerialize[Range[100]]]` is also greater than `ByteCount[Compress[Range[100]]]`.So what's purpose of this function? Anyone can provide a good example to use it?

Comment: see how it compares if you do `PerformanceGoal->"Size"`

Comment: @george2079 So it is for save space?Why not set `PerformanceGoal->"Size"` as a default option?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**
This answer is written from a user's point of view. For useful insider information on this topic see [this discussion with Mathematica developers on Community Forums](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1053802).

**Introduction**

Binary serialization is rewriting expressions as an array of bytes (list of integers from `Range[0, 255]`).
Binary representation of expression takes less space than a textual one and also can be exported and imported faster than text.

**How do `Compress` and `BinarySerialize` functions work?**

`Compress` (with default options) always does three steps:

1. It performs binary serialization.
2. It deflates result using `zlib`.
3. It transforms deflated result to a Base64-encoded text string.

`BinarySerialize` performs only binary serialization and sometimes deflates the result using `zlib`.
With default options it will decide itself if it wants to deflate or not.
With an option `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` it will avoid deflation.
With an option `PerformanceGoal -> "Size"` it will likely deflate.
`BinarySerialize` returns a `ByteArray` object.
`ByteArray` is something like a packed array of 8-bit integers.
However FullForm of ByteArray is visualized as Base64-encoded text string.
This visualization can be somewhat misleading, because internally ByteArrays are stored and operated in binary form, not as text strings.

**Binary serialization algorithms of `Compress` and `BinarySerialize`**

Original serialization algorithm of `Compress` is described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104696/47416).
That algorithm is not very optimized for size and produces larger-then-necessary output for many typical expressions.
For example, it has no support for packed arrays of integers and rewrites such arrays as nested lists, which take a lot bytes.

`BinarySerialize` uses a more size-optimized binary serialization algorithm compared to what `Compress` (with default options) does. This algorithm supports packed arrays of integers, has optimizations for integers of different size (8,16,32 bit),
stores big integers in binary form (not as text strings), and has other optimizations.

**Applications of `BinarySerialize`**

Using `BinarySerialize` we can write our own `Compress`-like functions with better compression.
For example we can write `myCompress` function which does the same three steps as original `Compress`,
but uses `BinarySerialize` for the serialization step:

```
myCompress[expr_]:=Module[
    {compressedBinaryData},
    compressedBinaryData = BinarySerialize[expr, PerformanceGoal->"Size"];
    Developer`EncodeBase64[compressedBinaryData]
    ];

myUncompress[string_]:=Module[
    {binaryData},
    binaryData = Developer`DecodeBase64ToByteArray[string];
    BinaryDeserialize[binaryData]
    ];
```

Even for simple integer list we can see size reduction.

```
Compress[Range[100]] // StringLength
(* 290 *)

myCompress[Range[100]] // StringLength
(* 244 *)

myUncompress[myCompress[Range[100]]] === Range[100]
(* True *)
```

If we take an expression with large number of small integers we get much more noticeable improvement:

```
bitmap = Rasterize[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]];

StringLength[Compress[bitmap]]
(*31246*)

StringLength[myCompress[bitmap]]
(*17820*)

myUncompress[myCompress[bitmap]] === bitmap
(* True *)
```

**Conclusion**

The example above shows that the result of a simple user-defined function `myCompress` based on a `BinarySerialize` can be almost *twice* more compact than the result of `Compress`.

**Outlook**

To decrease the output size even further one can use a compression algorithm with higher compression settings (in the second step)
or use `Ascii85`-encoding instead of `Base64` in the third step.

**Appendix 1: Undocumented options of `Compress`**

I have noticed that in Version 11.1 `Compress` has more undocumented options than in previous versions. Those options allows one to:

- Disable both compression and Base64 encoding and return a binary serialized result as a string with unprintable characters:

  `Compress[Range[100], Method -> {"Version" -> 4}]`
- Change binary serialization algorithm to a more efficient one, but not exactly to `BinarySerialize`.

  `Compress[Range[100], Method -> {"Version" -> 6}] // StringLength`

  `(* 254 *)`

There is also a `"ByteArray"` option shown in usage message `??Compress` but it does not work in Version 11.1.

Note that this behavior is undocumented and may change in future versions.

**Appendix 2: Compression option of `BinarySerialize`**

Just for fun one can manually compress result of `BinarySerialize[..., PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]` to get 
the same output as `BinarySerialize[..., PerformanceGoal -> "Size"]` produces.
This can be done with the following code:

```
myBinarySerializeSize[expr_]:=Module[
    {binaryData, dataBytes, compressedBytes},
    binaryData = Normal[BinarySerialize[expr, PerformanceGoal->"Speed"]];
    dataBytes = Drop[binaryData, 2]; (*remove magic "7:"*)
    compressedBytes = Developer`RawCompress[dataBytes];
    ByteArray[Join[ToCharacterCode["7C:"], compressedBytes]]
    ]
```

We can check that it gives the same result as `PerformanceGoal -> "Size"` option

```
data = Range[100];
myBinarySerializeSize[data] === BinarySerialize[data, PerformanceGoal -> "Size"]
```

**Appendix 3: `zlib` compression functions**

Description of undocumented `zlib` compression/decompression functions `` Developer`RawCompress `` and `` Developer`RawUncompress `` can be found in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140574/47416).

**Appendix 4: `Base64` encoding functions**

Usage of `Base64` encoding/decoding functions from the `` Developer` `` context can be explained using the following code:

```
binaryData = Range[0, 255];

Normal[
    Developer`DecodeBase64ToByteArray[
        Developer`EncodeBase64[binaryData]
        ]
    ] == binaryData

(* True *)
```

Comment: You seem to have dug deep here. Perhaps you have some of the answers for [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1053802) too.

Comment: I just feel very pity that ``Developer`RawCompress`` just can compress string or list.

Answer (score 7):

Measure the difference in bytes with [`ByteCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteCount.html).

```
BinarySerialize[Range[100]] // ByteCount
```

> ```
> 901
> ```

```
Range[100] // ByteCount
```

> ```
> 936
> ```

[`BinarySerialize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinarySerialize.html) will occupy fewer bytes.  Not a big difference in this trivial example but the difference generally widens as the object to be serialised gets larger.

Also you must [`Compress`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compress.html) both for apples-to-apples comparison.

```
Compress@BinarySerialize[Range[100]] // ByteCount
```

> ```
> 336
> ```

```
Compress@Range[100] // ByteCount
```

> ```
> 368
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So as your understand,this function is intend to save space?

Comment: @yode I think that's probably right. Also, and here I'm just speculating, it might be faster to revert using `BinaryDeserialize`. Of course the fact that it's a binary format also probably means it's not platform independent.

Comment: @MB1965 You mean if I share my result of `BinarySerialize` to you,you cannot decode it by `BinaryDeserialize`?

Comment: @MB1965 I would expect them to state it explicitly if it is not platform independent (as it is stated for the MX format).  `Compress` is platform independent.

Comment: @Szabolcs this is true... hmm... I have no Windows machines lying about but hopefully someone can test this and prove me wrong.

Comment: @yode Also if you look at the details you can either choose speed or space and it will automatically try to balance that.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an interesting complement to Edmund's answer. It's *not* always the case that the [`ByteArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteArray.html) form will be more compact. `DocFind` is just a table of reflinks I use for doc searching.

```
In[155]:= bs = BinarySerialize@DocFind[]; // RepeatedTiming

Out[155]= {1.8, Null}

In[156]:= cp = Compress@DocFind[]; // RepeatedTiming

Out[156]= {1.74, Null}

In[157]:= bs // ByteCount

Out[157]= 3027593

In[158]:= cp // ByteCount

Out[158]= 233104
```

On the other hand it's minimally faster to [`BinaryDeserialize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinaryDeserialize.html):

```
In[159]:= Uncompress@cp; // RepeatedTiming

Out[159]= {0.34, Null}

In[160]:= BinaryDeserialize@bs; // RepeatedTiming

Out[160]= {0.30, Null}
```

If we use a much larger input we get a much more interesting result, though:

```
In[145]:= bs2 = BinarySerialize@Range[10000000]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[145]= {0.16928, Null}

In[153]:= cp2 = Compress@Range[10000000]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[153]= {4.92081, Null}
```

My intuition would suggest that [`BinarySerialize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinarySerialize.html) should almost always be as fast or faster than [`Compress`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compress.html) but I'd be interested to be proven wrong.

Here the serialized version is much more compact:

```
In[161]:= bs2 // ByteCount

Out[161]= 80000104

In[162]:= bs3 // ByteCount

Out[162]= 31276128
```

And it's so much faster to use [`BinaryDeserialize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinaryDeserialize.html) here than [`Uncompress`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Uncompress.html):

```
In[163]:= BinaryDeserialize@bs2; // RepeatedTiming

Out[163]= {0.13, Null}

In[164]:= Uncompress@cp2; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[164]= {29.8372, Null}
```

Again, because it's a byte format, my intuition would suggest `Binary*` will be faster and often more compact than a compressed string.

#### Update: yode confirmed that it *is* platform independent

<s>On the other hand, since it's a byte format I would also believe it's platform dependent -- i.e., I can't take my serialized [`ByteArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteArray.html) and mail it to you and expect it to work if we have different operating systems/architecture, the same way I can't expect that of .mx files.</s>

Comment: I'm in window 10.Can we test whether it is platform dependent or not?

Comment: Run this code please.`NotebookPut[Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[Flatten[ImageData[Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/A2bMu.png"],"Byte"]]]]]`.Do you get `Range[100]` by `BinaryDeserialize`?

Comment: @yode for some reason that gave me an "file not found" message. Alternatively you can pull the byte array file [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/1a75a9f1-b3fd-4573-9071-f451ee84dcca) (just go there and the file will download) and see if you can get that to `BinaryDeserialize`.

Comment: I get it.[see this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh5mS.png).It is your file?

Comment: @yode yep. It's platform independent. I'll amend my post.

Comment: BTW MX is portable between OSs since 10.0, but not portable between 32 and 64 bit. MX written with older versions is also supposed to be readable with newer versions (perhaps only since v10.0)

Comment: @Szabolcs good to know. I just remembered reading that it wasn't in the docs at some point.

Comment: @MB1965 Could I know how do you export a `ByteArray` object to get [such file](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/1a75a9f1-b3fd-4573-9071-f451ee84dcca)?

Comment: @yode I exported to a file on my desktop and then used `CopyFile` to an object I got from `CloudDeploy[None, Permissions->"Public"]`. You'll need a cloud account to use it, but restricted cloud accounts are free, so that's all I do (if you need more you can do the Google Drive thing where you make a new email to get a new free account). You might be able to just set the `"MIMEType"` or something to get your object to autodownload... or maybe `CloudPut`. Dunno. I just use `CopyFile`.

Comment: I mean how to export it into your desktop. :)Like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Kss.png)?

Comment: @yode ohhh. I surely used some variant on `Export["~/Desktop/byte_array.m",barr]`.

Comment: But why your file [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/1a75a9f1-b3fd-4573-9071-f451ee84dcca) is a no file extension file?

Comment: @yode it's just a raw cloud object. Its file type is in its mime type. Since I copied it up from a .m file that's set to `application/vnd.wolfram.mathematica.package`. And your browser knows that to download links of that mime type.

Comment: I'm having some SSH oddities trying to import that, but the easiest thing is, I think, `CloudGet` although you can often use `ToExpression` on a raw `Import`, too. I can post a Q/A type question on sharing data via the cloud if that would be helpful to you.

Comment: @yode [it's up](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144130/sharing-data-via-the-cloud/144131#144131). Comment there to ask for more info / clarification.

Answer (score 3):

In general, serialization is widely used for two purposes:

1. To send large objects "over the wire" by TCP/IP from one computer to another.  For example, a company might have a programming object such as a BillOfMaterials containing a large number of part numbers.  The company would serialize the BillOfMaterials, send it to a vendor, and request a quote and an estimate of parts availability.  The vendor would de-serialize the BillOfMaterials, assign prices to the part numbers and indicate whether in stock, serialize the completed BillOfMaterials, and return the quote to the originating company.
2. Memoization. For recursive algorithms using bimomial (Binomial[...]) or multinomial (Multinomial[...]) coefficients, the integers involved become very large very fast.  Even computers with large amounts of RAM cannot keep intermediate results in core memory and still do useful work.  It is common to keep a dictionary or map (in Mathematica, an Association) of the results of computing a binomial or multinomial coefficient as a serialized object on disk.  The dictionary key is a concatenation of the binomial or multinomial arguments, and the dictionary value is the file name of the serialized result.  So, instead of recomputing the coefficient, it is read from disk and de-serialized.  The same basic idea could be used in Dynamic Programming, in which a large problem is split into many smaller problems.  Since the smaller problems may have to be solved over and over again, their solutions can be serialized to disk and recalled as needed.