# Sharing data via the cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I've got some stuff that I want to be able distribute to my <s>totally real</s> friends, but I don't want to have to email them every time I change something.

How can I set up sharing via the cloud?

Answer (score 17):

#### Tips:

When you put stuff in the cloud it's good to use your short URL in the URI (or copy it in after to shrink down the link length and scariness):

```
CloudPut[1, "user:b3m2a1/whee"]

CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/whee"]
```

---

The cloud happily makes this really easy. Say we just want to distribute some expression to someone. All we need is the following:

```
In[307]:= CloudExport[
 BinarySerialize["hello!"],
 "Package",
 Permissions -> "Public"
 ]

Out[307]= \
CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/5e6e9b45-1018-46c5-\
bd87-17693d883732"]
```

And then our friend can go to that link and the thing will download for them to work with. Or, better yet, they can import it directly into Mathematica:

```
In[308]:= CloudImport@CloudObject[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/5e6e9b45-1018-46c5-bd87-\
17693d883732"]

Out[308]= ByteArray[< 10 >]
```

For that they, too, will need a free cloud account, but if they don't want to do that all is not lost. The resource is still semi-accessible via [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html):

```
In[312]:= Import[CloudObject[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/5e6e9b45-1018-46c5-bd87-\
17693d883732"],
 "Text"
 ]

Out[312]= "(* Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com *)
\
ByteArray[\"NzpTBmhlbGxvIQ==\"]"
```

And a quick little [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) will extract what we need.

Note that this won't alway work absolutely as formatting can get wonky.

Furthermore, if we use a fixed URL:

```
In[319]:= CloudExport[
 BinarySerialize["hello!"],
 "Package",
 "hello-array",
 Permissions -> "Public"
 ]

Out[319]= \
CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-affd7b1c-ecb6-\
4ccc-8cc4-4d107e2bf04a/hello-array"]
```

our friend need only know one URL and the updating version will always be available

#### Packages

Where this really gets cool, though, is how you can distribute packages.

The [`CloudGet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudGet.html) function acts just like [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html) but for the cloud, and so if you have a package file and you copy it to the cloud via `CopyFile`, your friend can run `CloudGet` on that and all of your code will become immediately accessible to them.

#### Paclets

But wait! There's more!

We can set up a [paclet site in the cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141868/38205) so that our entire application can be easily distributed. And we can combine this with `CloudGet` to configure an auto-installer for our package. Run this:

```
CloudGet@"https://wolfr.am/l514yL7C"
```

and (assuming I haven't broken anything since I last tested it) you'll get the current version of a package of little tools I wrote. Note that I used [`URLShorten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLShorten.html) on the longer URL that that hides.

You can then uninstall this via:

```
CloudGet@"https://wolfr.am/l51cHPOm"
```

#### Standard HTML Content

Note, too, that the cloud can take standard HTML/CSS content, too.

I have code that will turn a PacletSite.mz into an [HTML page](http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/paclets/PacletServer/main.html) that can be deployed.

---

#### Update: full static websites

So going above and beyond what I'd done before with the cloud I recently wrote a system to push a full static website up there: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/building-websites-with-mathematica.html#main-content

The www.wolframcloud.com/objects is ugly, yes, but it's so convenient to just be able to push things from within Mathematica (as I write my posts and pages in Mathematica anyway).

Comment: @yode glad to help. Perhaps this will free you from having to distribute code as byte images through imgur (although I do enjoy the cleverness of that approach).

Comment: @MB1965 What is the purpose of `BinarySerialize` in your example?

Comment: @Shadowray it's just an arbitrary expression to distribute. This came out of a discussion with yode where we were working with it.