# How to decode Ascii85 format (AKA base85)?

Tags: string-manipulation, character-encoding

The [ASCII85 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) is a binary string encoding where every four bytes are encoded with five ASCII letters, using 85 different types of characters.

Unfortunately, it's not in $CharacterEncodings:

[image]

We can do this with [python](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/pdfminer/ascii85.py):

```
ascii85decode(b'9jqo^BlbD-BleB1DJ+*+F(f,q')
```

yields 'Man is distinguished', but how to do this in Mathematica?

**Related:**

- [What's purpose of the new function BinarySerialize?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141885/whats-purpose-of-the-new-function-binaryserialize/141930#141930)

Comment: The python code example which do the conversion can be directly ported to MMA, what is a problem? The built-in way is absent.

Comment: Of course it can be, I’m asking if there’s any built in way

Comment: You are *only* interested in a built-in way, or is a fast, terse, or elegant implementation of interest as well? (I don't have anything yet, just clarifying.)

Comment: Yes I think I’m interested in any answer